# EA 12, How to limit generated sequence name length to be 30 character?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm using Enterprise Architect 12, after generating DDL (Oracle DB) sequence name is a combination between table name and column name so sequence name length is more than 30 character.

How to limit sequence name to 30 character or change transformation template to be 30 character not more.

Comment: I don't use the transformation any more (instead I use my own scripts). But IIRC the macro language has no string computation concept. So probably you are out of luck using it.

Comment: As an additional idea: you may use EXEC_ADD_IN to do string manipulation from within an add-in you write.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible but the way is not easy. You have to modify the DDL templates, which are responsible for rendering of final script. I use EA 12, so all provided information are valid for this version

1. Open DDL templates for edit. Menu **PACKAGE >> DATABASE ENIGINEERING >> EDIT DDL TEMPLATES**
2. Choose "Language", set "Oracle" in this case.
3. Choose Template with name "DDL column Extras"
4. Find the part, where sequence name is prepared, in my case, line 16-20

Add new line under the line

```
$sequenceName = "SEQ_" + $tableName + "_" + $columnName
```

new line is:

```
$sequenceName=%MID($sequenceName,0,30)%
```

(I have no idea why it is not possible to do it in one line, so I needed to create the name first, and cut it after it.)

Be aware first time of correct syntax (Using '%' around the MID macro).

Be aware second time of cutting of chars. Theoretical you can create duplicite sequences.

Of course, probably you will have the same issue with trigger name, I hope, the same solution will help.